# Pass data from a component to Util file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass `data` from a React component to another and struggling to understand how I can call this `data` to the destination file

Basically want to pass a `<input />` value from a `component.js` to a function within the `Util.js` file.

So far I have the following attempt within my `component.js`:

```
const [distance, setDistance] = useState();

function handleChange(value){
    setDistance(value.target.value);
}

return {
    <input className="input" name="distance" type={`number`} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

`Util.js`

```
export const filterByDistance = function(){       
}
```

So to call it will I need to do something like this?

```
import {distance} from './component.js';
```

Comment: This mean util does not have a value and depends on the component so you need to import util funtion in the component then when you have a value call the util function and pass the value

Comment: How are you planning on using `filterByDistance`? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to import the variable from `component.js` to `Utils.js` you should do it the other way around: import the `Util.js` function into `component.js` then call it.

```
import { filterByDistance } from './Util.js';

const [distance, setDistance] = useState();

function handleChange(value){
    setDistance(value.target.value);
    filterByDistance(value.target.value)
}

return { ... }
```

Then accept the value as an argument:

```
export const filterByDistance = function(value){  
    console.log(value)     
}
```

Comment: Since `util` isn't a component it should start with a lowercase `u`.